# Can nusoap return array of string?

Tags: web-services, nusoap

I would like to return an array of string in my web services

I've tryed :

```
<?php
require_once('nusoap/nusoap.php');

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL('NewsService', 'urn:NewsService');
$server->register('GetAllNews', 
 array(),
 array('return' => 'xsd:string[]'),
 'urn:NewsService',
 'urn:NewsService#GetAllNews',
 'rpc',
 'literal',
 ''
);

// Define the method as a PHP function
function GetAllNews()
{
 $stack = array("orange", "banana");
 array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
 return $stack;
}
```

but it doesn't work. What is the correct syntax for that ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to define a new type that describes an array of strings like so:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
  'ArrayOfString',
  'complexType',
  'array',
  'sequence',
  '',
  array(
    'itemName' => array(
      'name' => 'itemName', 
      'type' => 'xsd:string',
      'minOccurs' => '0', 
      'maxOccurs' => 'unbounded'
    )
  )
);
```

Then you can use `tns:ArrayOfString` as the return type.

Comment: How do I convert the data type of $stack (a simple array of string in php) to ArrayOfString so that I can get the data of $stack as ArrayOfString in my client code (C#) ?

Comment: @Ankit: Sorry, can't help you with that. I wrote this a long time ago.

Comment: @Computer User you return the value directly and it will be casted automaticly

Answer (score 1):

This site describes a nice way to return complex datatypes and receive it with C#: http://sanity-free.org/125/php_webservices_and_csharp_dotnet_soap_clients.html

Comment: This site's code works with WCF. Don't use SEQUENCE (leave the composition parameter to AddComplexType blank), but instead use the restriction type "SOAP-ENC:Array".

Answer (score 1):

When returning array of arrays, you might need a different configuration from Oliver. For example phfunc2php uses this technique in the nusoapcode.class.php file (https://github.com/sylnsr/pgfunc2php/blob/master/nusoapcode.class.php). The code it generates looks like so:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'ArrayOfArrays','complexType','array','',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')));
```

and then the functions simply needs to return "tnsArrayOfArrays:

```
$server->register(
    'sel_signon_id_by_uuid',
    array('user_uuid' => 'xsd:string'),
    array('return'=>'tns:ArrayOfArrays'),
```

The project mentioned above can compile working code for you, should you want to see this.