# Convert an array of string in php to an user defined data type in nuSOAP

Tags: c#, php, web-services, nusoap

In continuation to the existing question: [Can nusoap return array of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629028/can-nusoap-return-array-of-string)

I want to know the code for function GetAllNews() to return string of array $stack as data type "tns:ArrayOfString"

Mr. Oliver Salzburg gave the code only for the declaration of type ArrayOfString but how do I convert a normal php array of string data type to user defined data type ArrayOfString ? So that I can call this data in my C# code as:

```
wService.Service WebS = new wService.Service();
wService.ArrayOfString StringArray = new wService.ArrayOfString();
StringArray = WebS.GetAll();
string [] All= StringArray.itemName[0];
```

My aim is to return an array of string from php/nuSOAP to my C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define ArrayOfString above the code as

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'ArrayOfString',
'complexType',
'array',
'all',
'SOAP-ENC:Array',
array(),
array(
array(
   'ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
   'wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]'
   )
),
'xsd:string'
);
```

Then declare method 'GetAllNews' as

```
$server->register('GetAllNews', 
 array(),
 array('return' => 'tns:ArrayOfString'),  //use 'tns:ArrayOfString' instead of 'xsd:string[]'
 'urn:NewsService',
 'urn:NewsService#GetAllNews',
 'rpc',
 'literal',  //You can also use 'encoded'
 ''
);
```

The above code will return an array of string (`string []`) Call the method 'GetAllNews' in C# as

```
string [] AllNews = new WebService.GetAllNews();
```